# How to find Gmail address from gmailId -GoogleSignIn

Tags: android, ios, email, authentication, gmail-api

We use Gmail login in our mobile application,

but recently we discovered that lots of users don't have e-mail addresses in our database. But they have GmailId in our databases.
We use GoogleSignIn for getting Gmail information.
After the tests, we saw that sometimes that API doesn't bring the Gmail address.
If we don't get the mail address we only insert gmailid to our database.

How can we find Gmail addresses from gmaildIds.

example gmaild Id= 116333385622785111111